# How to get query from two different tables as single table

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
Tab1        
id  Name    Level
1   a1  1
2   a2  1
3   b1  2
4   b2  2
5   c1  3
6   c2  3
7   b3  2
8   c3  3
9   c4  3


Tab2        
id  linkid  
1   3   
3   6   
1   7   
7   8   
3   9
```

I am trying to fetch different levels of id which falls for level = 1
something like

```
Tab3        
Level1  Level2  Level3
1   3   6
1   7   8
1   3   9
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I do not get the logic in your Tab3 results. Could you develop a little?

Answer (score 0):

Following statement is sufficient for the data you've presented ...

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  lvl1.id AS Level1
        , lvl2.id AS Level2
        , lvl3.id AS Level3
FROM    Tab2 lvl1
        INNER JOIN Tab2 lvl2 ON lvl2.id = lvl1.linkid
        INNER JOIN Tab2 lvl3 ON lvl3.id = lvl2.linkid
WHERE   lvl1.id = 1
```

... but I assume you somehow need `Tab1` incorporated into the results so this might be closer to what you really require

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  lvl1.id AS Level1
        , lvl2.id AS Level2
        , lvl3.id AS Level3
FROM    Tab1 t1 
        INNER JOIN Tab2 lvl1 ON lvl1.id = t1.id
        INNER JOIN Tab2 lvl2 ON lvl2.id = lvl1.linkid
        INNER JOIN Tab2 lvl3 ON lvl3.id = lvl2.linkid
WHERE   t1.id = 1
```

*note that I assume `Tab2.id` being a foreign key to `Tab1.id`*